# Symfony 6.2 Warning: session_id(): Session ID cannot be changed after headers have already been sent

Tags: symfony

При отправке любой формы Symfony не важно FormType или обычная форма выскакивает вот такая ошибка.
[image: Ошибка]

после отправки формы над Symfony выводом выводятся данные формы.